# GET //socket.io/ 404 error with Express and Apache ProxyPass

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to create a web app using socket.io, express, and node.js. On my Ubuntu server, I have Apache proxying any requests for the url (example.com/game) to the express web server (http://localhost:3000). The proxy works, as the index page does load.

However, I can't get the client's socket.io requests to connect. All of socket.io's requests for `http://example.com/game/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1422809869665-0` return a `404 Not Found` error. (From the express debug log: `GET //socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1422809724117-0 404 51.746 ms - 2213`.)

Frustratingly, the code works on my Windows desktop, but not when I push it to my web server.

Relevant code snippets on the server:

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('game-simulation:server');
var http = require('http');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

app.enable('trust proxy');

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);

var io = require('socket.io')(server, { path: '/socket.io/'});
```

In the client side javascript:

```
var url = document.location.protocol+'//'+document.location.host;
var socket = io.connect(url, {path: '/game/socket.io/'});
```

My Apache proxy configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # ServerName, log files, directory, etc. ...

  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPass /game http://localhost:3000/ connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30
  ProxyPassReverse /game http://localhost:3000
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?